# Creating shortcut to a special folder like Control Panel or Computer Management

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

There are lots of samples to create shortcut to a file or folder, but all I have is object GUID, like {9438384-39393-394848-439498} (not a real one). I can't understand where I can resolve guid to idlist in [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776891%28VS.85%29.aspx#Shellink_Creating_Shortcut_Nonfile) about creating shortcut to a non-file object.

Comment: Hot on the heels of Raymond Chen's [Finding a printer, and then creating a shortcut to that printer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/01/28/10388715.aspx). It may be helpful.

Comment: There is SHGetSpecialFolderPath and SHGetKnownFolderIDList which can do the most of special folders, however still no solution to use GUID object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution was easy. Use **shell:::{94308384-3939-3948-4394-4498}** as path for the folder and create it as usual.